# Confusion with app review by Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the Facebook SDK for Android v3.5. I have used the native login that comes with the SDK. I submitted my app for review and this is the feedback that I received.

General Feedback: Your Android app must use the native Login dialog that comes with Facebook's SDKs instead of custom web views. Ensure you have successfully tested your Facebook Login integration for Single Sign On or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more details here

I have already used native login with the SDK. I'm attaching the screenshots of my application.
Please Help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you just using the LoginButton as supplied in the SDK? What happens if you don't have the facebook app installed?

Comment: If there is no facebook app, a webview pops up, asking for user credentials. I havent implemented this webview, I assume this is the functionality of the SDK. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm, if you haven't modified the SDK at all, and are just using the LoginButton, then it should be OK. I would resubmit.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: Yaa the problem was resolved. Just resubmitted it.